# Hibernate 3. BatchSize Fetching. Entities in collection are treated as unique objects (and they are not)

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of classes that relate through a many-to-many relationship to another collection of classes. Students have many Roles.

I used BatchSize(size=15) on the Set of Roles from within Student class in order to prevent the N+1 problem of hitting the DB on ever time getRoles() is called on every student.

I only have 15 Roles in the database table (hence the BatchSize of 15)
However, what I have noticed after running the app is that Hibernate attempts to load 15 Roles up front and then loads more and more as it needs to as I iterate over the collection of Students.

Does it not understand that all these Roles are the same ? And are simply shared between all the Students ? The 15 Roles are brought into SessionContext a bunch of times. Even if I load up all 15 Roles through a separate HQL query up front, the database is still hit when I call getRoles() on the very 1st student.

So I set BatchSize to 1500 to allow Hiberante load AAAALLLL the Roles up front. That didn't work either. On 1st query it loaded 186 then on the 2nd query another 100 and 126 thereafter. 3 db hits are better than 363 (number of Students in list), but still there must be a better way.

My level2 cache is turned off, but I don't think this has anything to do with this.

Thank you for your time.